# Función que genere 10 arreglos en python

Tags: python

Necesito generar arreglos donde el mas pequeño es de 10 elementos  y el más grande de 10 deben ser de manera aleatoria, hasta el momento solo puedo generar uno.

```
for n in range (10):

 n = [random.randint(0,1000) for _ in range(n)]
 print n
```

Pero ahora necesito generar los otros 9 con un aumento de 10 en 10.

```
for n in range (10,110,10):

n = [random.randint(0,1000) for _ in range(n)]
print n
```

Pero con esto solo retorna un arreglo.

Comment: Solo como pequeña recomendación, no deberías reutilizar nombres de variables dentro y en la cabecera de un ciclo. Eso puede generar problemas inesperados.

Answer (score 0):

No entendí cómo querías calcular los valores

> donde el mas pequeño es de 10 elementos y el más grande de 10 deben ser de manera aleatoria

Pero igual quise ver que pasaba, así que ejecuté tu código, y solo puse `print` dentro del loop y me mostró los 10 arreglos (1 x 1)

```
import random

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for n in range(10, 110, 10):
        n = [random.randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(n)]
        print(n)

# Resultado            
# [954, 578, 849, 473, 62, 971, 417, 107, 926, 385]
# [488, 264, 753, 735, 2, 281, 592, 211, 73, 540, 430, 140, 868, 654, 602, 938, 984, 563, 544, 690]
# [966, 437, 591, 181, 196, 913, 15, 430, 830, 855, 417, 556, 953, 846, 357, 50, 648, 610, 302, 223, 768, 636, 689, 881, 538, 243, 356, 673, 433, 194]
.. Más arreglos
```

Ahora, si quieres retornar un arreglo de arreglos, puedes hacer esto:

```
import random

if __name__ == '__main__':
    master = []
    for n in range(10, 110, 10):
        master.append([random.randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(n)])

    print(master)
```

Suerte, R6

Comment: Estimado ahora comprendo que el print estaba fuera del loop por ende solo me mostraba un solo arreglo. Ahora necesito realizar un Quick sort pero a los 10 arreglos ¿puedo hacerlo de esta manera?

Comment: LMGTFY, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/ ahi tienes un full ejemplo en python.  Suerte.  Ps. En stack (EN) encontre mas ejemplos https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262306/quicksort-with-python

Comment: se agradece la info